# Is it possible to have negative PSNR?

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

I have been working on image processing. I have an image and then add it a Gaussian noise with standard deviation=0.005. then using averaging filter to denoise it (I know it is not a good idea). then I got negative PSNR. what this means? I think PSNR is a positive measurement.
the code for calculating PSNR is as follow:

```
function psnr1=PSNR(I,J)

mse1=(double(I)-double(J)).^2;
MSE1m=(mse1(:,:,1,:)+mse1(:,:,2,:)+mse1(:,:,3,:))/3;
psnr1=10*log10(255^2/mean(mean(MSE1m)));

end
```

what is wrong?
the final results for my code is these curves:
[image: avg means averaging filter is applied and W is window size]

Comment: If the MSE is very small, then you should most certainly get negative dB values for PSNR. It just means that the smoothing of the small-variance noise does much better than smoothing the noise with the higher variance.

Comment: @PeterK. but 'I' is my original image and 'J' is noise-reduced form noisy image with noise power=0.005 using an averaging filter. Why it is not negative for avg var=0.05 with the same window size?

Comment: Remember that dB is the logarithm of a value.  A negative log simply means that the original value was less than 1.0.  For instance log10(0.0001) = -4.

Comment: @simonB, I know it but what i do not understand why it is negative since the same PSNR for var=0.05 is positive and is more than 4. how can I justify it? noise power,var=0.005, is reduced considerably so we should have some better PSNR than var=0.05.

Comment: @peterk, if MSE becomes smaller then the PSNR will be very large not negative. If MSE has a large value and bigger than 255^2 the  PSNR will be negative. Notice that PSNR and MSE have inverse relation.

Comment: Right!  But that still means the PSNR can be negative, or do you have a different question now?

Comment: @peterk, what does it mean? How we can justify having negative PSNR in a video sequence?  Mse1 should be less than 255^2?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting the 255^2 from? Does that mean the video is $255 \times 255$ ? Yes, you're right, though, it is a little strange...

Comment: @peterk, 255^2 is the biggest value that a pixel can get.

Comment: Isn't that 255? Or are you using 16 bit pixels? 255^2 is the square of the largest pixel value...?

Comment: @peterk, yes exactly.

Comment: OK, so I'm wondering if what is happening is that one (or several) pixels are going outside the range 0 to 255, causing a wrapping or clipping error? That would explain getting HUGE errors for smaller noise.

Comment: @peterk, yes, i added a gaussian noise to a video sequence and the averaging filter with window size W=9 represents  negative values for all frames (see above figure). I tried the algorithm on severa, videos with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the [Peak Signal to Noise Ratio][1] (PSNR) its value is:

$$ PSNR = 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{{max}^{2} \left( I \right)}{MSE} \right) $$

If the MSE is larger than ${max}^{2} \left( I \right)$ (set to $255^2$) in the code above, then the fraction will be smaller than one and the logarithm will result in a negative value.

The code assumes the input image used 8-bit integer values for its pixels (max value is 255), but the images you compare have differences that are larger than that. Either the noise added to one is very large, or you are dealing with 12-bit or 16-bit images.

In general, the PSNR is negative when the noise is larger than the peak signal.